# ActiveRecord Association for Grades App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, activerecord, associations

A bit hard to explain with a title.

I am making a test grades app with Ruby on Rails, and can't figure out the best ActiveRecord Association setup.

Ideally: there are many Users, and there are many Tests. I need to store the each User's Scores from each Test. Right now I have this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests
  has_many :scores, :through => :tests
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :scores
end

class Scores < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :tests
end
```

Doesn't seem right though. I would like to know the convention for this. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I think it might be useful to note that this is really a database design question, and the fact that Rails' ActiveRecord is laid on top of the tables is an incidental detail. I'm not criticizing the question; I just thought it would be interesting to point that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use three tables/models:

1. `test`
2. `user` (or, possibly better, `student`)
3. `test_result`, having a `test_id`, `user_id` and `score`

Corresponding Ruby code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tests, through: :test_results
end

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, through: :test_results
end

class TestResult < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: So it test_result would belong_to test and user?

Comment: It's `tests` through `test_results`, and not the other way around, because `test_results` is what connects `tests` to `users`. Think about it this way: the only reason I have a relationship to any particular test is because I took that test. If I were to take a US Presidents test and a Civil War test, `jason.tests` would return those two tests, and not a Trigonometry test because I didn't take one. Hopefully that way of thinking makes it clear.